# Notepad++ save adds weird characters

Tags: text, notepad++, byte-order-mark

I'm trying to run a task on the Worker Role. I added a file named `Startup.cmd` with the following content:

```
icacls "PDFs" /grant Users:(OI)(CI)F
EXIT /B 0
```

All this does is give the `Users` group full control to the `PDFs` folder. The task does run because  the Microsoft Azure Activity Log window shows the message `Details: Starting role... Application startup tasks are running. [2015-02-04T23:39:28Z]` when the Worker Role is deployed. I then log into the machine using Remote Desktop and the security on the folder is not as expected. I then try to run the command manually and I see this:

[image]

The file has some weird characters which is making the command fail: `∩╗┐icacls`.

Can Azure Publishing be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your script is being saved with a [byte order marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Try saving the script as ascii or as UTF-8 without a BOM. That might work out better for you.

Comment: That was it. I typed the file with Notepad++, saved it, and added it to the project and voila, it is now working. Thank you!